# I want to zip file under PHP 7.1.6,

Tags: php

I want to zip file under PHP 7.1.6
AME="openSUSE Leap"
VERSION="42.2"
PEAR Version: 1.10.1
PHP Version: 7.1.6
Zend Engine Version: 3.1.0
Running on: Linux linux-2ifi 4.4.70-18.9-default #1 SMP Wed May 31 09:09:25 UTC 2017 (c1231a7) x86_

I can only download empty zip files, not able to identify were things are wrong, can someone help me in this

I have a bunch of *.xml files, that needs to be zipped as xmlfiles.zip and download.

```html
//ob_end_flush();

//$files = glob("*xml");
$files = array('*.xml');
//echo "<pre>";print_r($files);die;
if (is_array($files)) {
 // and proceed with your code
 $zipname = 'xmlfiles.zip';
 $zip = new ZipArchive;
 $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
 foreach ($files as $file) {
   $zip->addFile($file);
 }
 $zip->close();
 header('Content-Type: application/zip');
 header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
 header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
 readfile($zipname);
 
}
```

Comment: what is the `print_r()` of `$files`?

Comment: that's to check the value while debugging

Comment: Do you see any error-messages ? And could you include them ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Does the debug values help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$files = array("*xml");` line is trying to find a particular *.xml file and not all the xml files in the directory

Okay so uncomment the line

```
$files = glob("*.xml");
```

and comment

```
$files = array("*.xml");
```

The glob() function returns an array of filenames or directories matching a specified pattern.

Comment: I did not see any error , except a 0 byte zip file download, any specific library file I have to look for

Comment: Did your try your code with a single file? Try doing that and see wheter it is working or not.

Comment: its the same, I have feel I am missing some library

Comment: You don't need any library

Comment: okay I think I got your problem , why did you comment the glob line? The array line `$files = array('*.xml');` is trying to find a particular *.xml file. Use glob

Comment: I have changed the answer , try doing what is there and it should work.

Comment: i changed the code as per your advice , I get the following errors in the downloaded zip file, it aculaly ascii file, downloaded with a .zip extension 
<b>Warning</b>:  filesize(): stat failed for xmlfiles.zip in <b>/srv/www/htdocs/xml/xml.php</b> on line <b>529</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  readfile(xmlfiles.zip): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>/srv/www/htdocs/xml/xml.php</b> on line <b>530</b><br />

Comment: i have files names AIAPN6156E_ITR-1_2017_N_9720.xml , AIBPN4556B_ITR-1_2017_N_4520.xml, may be I need to read the files in a different method .

Comment: the cange that you are talking about - is it the uncomment change? or did you remove the header line?

Comment: See write back the header - content-length wala line back to your code and then un-comment the glob line and comment the array line

Comment: /ob_end_flush();

$files = glob("*xml");
//$files = array('*.xml');
//echo "<pre>";print_r($files);die;
if (is_array($files)) {
 // and proceed with your code
 $zipname = 'xmlfiles.zip';
 $zip = new ZipArchive;
 
 $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
 foreach ($files as $file) {
   $zip->addFile($file);
  
 }
 $zip->close();
 header('Content-Type: application/zip');
 header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
 header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
 readfile($zipname);
 
}

Comment: do `$files=glob("*.xml")`

Comment: you forgot the *. in that, this will search anyfile that is in your current directory having .xml extension

Comment: can you accept the answer then.. it would be helpful :) cheers

Comment: Where is the link to accept the answer, I searched for the keyword could not find it

Comment: check the right tick sign under the down array - on the left hand side of the answer

Comment: People gave a different approach to the same issues, this code was written by a freelance and for some reason he has commented the "glob" also removed the "." in the xml variable. thanks a ton Vishal next time I will be more careful working with Freelances.